# Getting error while loading Tibco BW designer

Tags: java, web-services, tibco, tibco-business-works

I have created webservice but While loading my webservice in tibco designer am getting below error.(Tibco BW 5.9)
can you please suggest.
thanks in advance.

**Error in [InvokeWebservice/InvokeProcess/Process Definition.process/SOAPRequestReply]
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/jms/JMSException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**

Regards,
Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need udpate the version java in the instalation tibco.

In the path `<TibcoHom>\tra\5.X\bin` execute the command  `traUpgradeManager`.This tool updates jre in all .tra files in all tibco components from 
 location provided.  you can upgrade full instalation or the especific folder. Please find the example

1. `traUpgradeManager -path C:/tibco -jre C:/tibco/jre/1.6.0` full instalation.
2. `traUpgradeManager -path C:/tibco/bw/5.6 -jre C:/tibco/jre/1.6.0` especific folder.

> traUpgradeManager (-path   | -include
>    [-exclude ] ) 
>           [-traversion ] [-rv ]
>           [-keepRVDir] [-jre ]
>           [-hawk ] [-nohawk] )
>          | -revert | -help
>
> -path        - If a directory, substitute all the .tra files in this directory and all directories under it; if a file name, substitute in
>   this file.
>
> -include     - The location of a file containing one entry per line that each act as .
>
> -exclude     - The location of a file containing one name per line which will be excluded from replacement. The name can match either a
>   directory or a file.  It is not the path, just a simple name.
>
> -traversion  - tra version number.
>
> -rv          - The full path of rv version to be used.
>
> -ems          - The full path of EMS version to be used.
>
> -jre         - The location of a JRE to use.  If not specified, will use the version associated with target TRA.
>
> -hawk        - The location of Hawk.  If neither -hawk or -nohawk is specified,               will use highest version of hawk installed.
>
> -nohawk      - Do not update the hawk home directory
>
> -keepRVDir   - If not specified, any instances of RV_HOME/lib in the classpath will be replaced with RV_HOME/lib/tibrvj.jar.
>
> -revert      - Revert the latest substituation by removing the tra file and rename the bak file to it.
>
> -help        - Print this help information, but take no action.
>
> Examples    traUpgradeManager -include C:/temp/include.txt 
>   -traversion 5.6 -exclude C:/temp/exclude.txt   traUpgradeManager -path C:/tibco/tra/5.6/bin/DeleteInvalidUsers.tra -jre C:/tibco/jre/1.6.0
>   traUpgradeManager -path C:/tibco/bw/5.6 -jre C:/tibco/jre/1.6.0
>   traUpgradeManager -path C:/tibco -jre C:/tibco/jre/1.6.0
>   traUpgradeManager -path C:/tibco -ems C:/tibco/ems/7.0
>   traUpgradeManager -revert -path C:/tibco/bw/5.6

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you Designer is running an older version of Java that is not supported by your Tibco EMS libraries.

So either you have to upgrade the JVM of the designer to be compliant with the EMS client library requirements or you install an older version of the EMS client libraries.

PS: connecting to a newer version of EMS from an older client library version is supported.

Comment: Hi Walter,
Thanks for reply and i have updated java version to latest version but no use still getting same error. is there any way to upgrade designer JVM.
i am using Java 1.8.0_101 version.

Comment: designer.tra values below
tibco.env.JVM_LIB_DIR D:/tibco/tibcojre/1.6.0/bin/client
tibco.env.JVM_LIB_SERVER_DIR D:/tibco/tibcojre/1.6.0/bin/server
tibco.env.JVM_LIB_PATH D:/tibco/tibcojre/1.6.0/bin/server/jvm.dll

Comment: tibco.env.CUSTOM_CP_EXT

Comment: D:/tibco/bw/5.9/../plugins/lib/bc;D:/tibco/drivers/win_sapjco;D:/tibco/adapter/adr3/6.1/hotfix/lib/palettes;D:/tibco/adapter/adr3/6.1/lib/palettes;D:/tibco/adapter/adadb/6.1/hotfix/lib;D:/tibco/adapter/adadb/6.1/lib;D:/tibco/adapter/adadb/6.1/lib/palettes;%TPCL_HOME%/lib/httpclient_3.0;D:/tibco/bw/5.9/hotfix/lib/engine.jar;D:/tibco/bw/5.9/hotfix/lib/mapper.jar;D:/tibco/bw/5.9/lib/engine.jar;D:/tibco/bw/5.9/lib/mapper.jar;%HAWK_HOME%/lib;D:/tibco/bw/5.9/hotfix/lib;D:/tibco/bw/5.9/lib;D:/tibco/bw/5.9/lib/palettes;%TPCL_HOME%/uddi4j/lib/uddi4j.jar;

Comment: ;D:/tibco/bw/plugins/lib;D:/tibco/bw/plugins/lib/palettes;